# How can I optimize this Nhibernate HQL query?

Tags: nhibernate, query-optimization, hql

This is one of the more complex HQL queries I've written.  I'm still pretty new to HQL at this capacity and could use some feedback.

One thing I would do in native sql is change the date comarison stuff to come from a single query as a table, i.e.

```
FROM 
(
    SELECT MIN, MAX
    FROM ..
) T
```

Here's the method:

```
public IList<Order> GetOrdersBy(string referenceNumber = null, int? customerId = null, int? carrierId = null, DateTime? startDate = null,
            DateTime? endDate = null, int? websiteId = null, OrderStatus? status = null)
        {


            var byStatusHql =
            @"
            select odor
            from Order odor
            join fetch odor._orderStatusLog statusLog
            where 
            (:referenceNumber is null or odor.Quote.ReferenceNumber=:referenceNumber) and
            (:customerId is null or odor.Quote.Customer.CustomerID=:customerId) and
            (:carrierId is null or odor.Quote.Carrier.CarrierID=:carrierId) and
            (:websiteId is null or odor.Quote.Customer.Website.WebsiteID=:websiteId) and
            (
                :startDate is null or :startDate >
                (select min(CreatedDate) from OrderStatusLog lg where lg in elements(odor._orderStatusLog))
            ) and
            (
                :endDate is null or :endDate <= 
                (select max(CreatedDate) from OrderStatusLog lg where lg in elements(odor._orderStatusLog))
            ) and
            (
                :status is null or :status = 
                (
                    select Status from OrderStatusLog lg where lg in elements(odor._orderStatusLog) 
                    and lg.OrderStatusLogID = (select max(OrderStatusLogID) from OrderStatusLog lgg where lgg in elements(odor._orderStatusLog))
                )

            )
            ";

            var query = Session.CreateQuery(byStatusHql);
            query.SetParameter("referenceNumber", referenceNumber)
                 .SetParameter("customerId", customerId)
                 .SetParameter("carrierId", carrierId)
                 .SetParameter("websiteId", websiteId)
                 .SetParameter("startDate", startDate)
                 .SetParameter("endDate", endDate)
                 .SetParameter("status", status)
            ;

            return query.List<Order>();            
        }
```

Comment: Ever considered to use Criteria or QueryOver? They are much better in dynamic queries, where you only add the filter criteria that are actually used.

Comment: I considered it, but when things get more complex, both of those are pretty complicated to read and understand, imo.  I totally get linq and had it written originally using groupby but I got a NotImplemented error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "Optimize" in terms of performance or readability?

Considering performance, I would use Criteria or QueryOver to add only the filter arguments that are actually used. Criteria is not that powerful and the syntax in this case would be more complicated, but it is easier to dynamically compose the query.

You can try to use a single subquery for the aggregates on the log:

```
and exists (
    select min(CreatedDate), max(CreatedDate), max(OrderStatusLogID) 
    from OrderStatusLog lg 
    where lg in elements(odor._orderStatusLog)
    having 
      :startDate is null or :startDate > min(CreatedDate)
      and :endDate is null or :endDate <= max(CreatedDate)
      and :status is null or :status = (
        select lgg.Status from OrderStatusLog lgg 
        where lgg.id = max(OrderStatusLogID)))
```

I don't know if it all work. The last one, with the Status, may be too much for a having clause.

However, it performs not very well, because there are subqueries that could be omitted when the parameters are null. I doubt that the DBMS is smart enough to optimize it away.

Comment: Readability and performance suggestions appreciated.  Thanks for suggestion.  I would still need the CreatedDate property from your change, which I tried last night.  My test in Sqlite always left that section blank, leading me to believe it couldn't figure it out.

I would have loved to use Criteria or QueryOver, but I couldn't get it to work due to my lack of understanding of the constructs and my time constraints.  I posted to the nhusers and received no love, so went with what I knew I could get working.

Comment: I think I missed the CreatedDate part, this doesn't work. I'll remove it.